# Strange user profile occurrence (possibly relating to account merging?)

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, accounts, merge-accounts

I was visiting the [New Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers) as I've frequently done this month, to see who was coming close to me (because I proudly am *first* on the list :), when I noticed a user I hadn't seen before.

According to that page, [Red Bottle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17450994/red-bottle) made **1,849 reputation** *in one day*. Looking at their account, I see "Member since today" (more precisely: 2021-11-18 20:12:17Z UTC).  I also see they've asked 98 questions, far more than the 50-per-day limit I've seen somewhere...

All of their question badges, such as ["Famous Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=17450994), were *all* awarded about 1 hour ago.

It also says that they don't participate in *any* tags.

Another very odd thing I noticed with this profile is that, of all three gray cards at the top of the user profile, the reputation one is abnormally spare for a user with that much rep. The progress bar showing their progress towards their next privilege stretches the whole card.

Compare Red Bottle's:

[image: Red Bottle's profile with 1,849 reputation]

to mine:

[image: user17242583's profile with 2,719 reputation]

Is any of this unexpected?

Comment: Most likely, yes, a merge, but that might not be information that can be confirmed beyond speculation

Comment: Looks like it was an *un*merge

Comment: Follow-up question: what's an *un*merge?

Comment: That sounds interesting @Zoe - what do you mean?

Comment: i suppose that would mean, a new account was created, and stuff from another account was moved to it. i've never heard of such a thing here. The user id would support that

Comment: well, the opposite of a merge. Looks like there was a merge that was undone. The activity log includes "User.Unmerge()". Mods cannot unmerge accounts, but staff (specifically devs, AFAIK), and generally happens when a merge was bad. I have no idea what the details of the situation are in this particular case (and probably wouldn't have been able to share them anyway), but it looks like a bad merge took place, and was reverted. The TL;DR: in either case is that this may be an artefact of reversing a merge, as opposed to an artefact caused by the merge itself

Comment: That said, it took place an hour ago, so the system might just need time to recalculate on its own. There's a lot of stuff that's cached, and may just need time to catch back up. If not, this might be a bug or just require staff to kick some applicable caches

Comment: @KevinB "*i suppose that would mean, a new account was created, and stuff from another account was moved to it. i've never heard of such a thing here.*" I'm pretty sure that when a user makes a new account with an already registered email, the accounts are automatically merged. I remember seeing a Q on MSE maybe a year ago where a user fell victim to that.

Comment: well, yea, that'd be a merge, not an unmerge, the unmerge is the thing I haven't heard of.

Comment: How did you get so much reputation to be the first one on the list?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Dharman! :) [tag:pandas] is the answer. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All of what you see is completely expected, for both merges and the rarely used unmerge option.

In the event of a merge, we do not copy badge information and some other information. This can result in all their badges that weren't on the base account being re-awarded in quick succession as those script run again. Depending on the state of the account being merged into, the final account may have a lot of information or little to no information regarding their tag scores and ranks. Some of those take a while to update - tag scores are only calculated once a day. Because the cached information shows they haven't participated in any tags yet, you'll see nothing about the tags or any suggested tag badge for them to pursue.

In the event of an unmerge, all of those things are guaranteed to be empty. Technically speaking, a new profile is created because it's not possible to "undelete" the old profile. That means it gets a new creation date and an empty cache of information. The profile would have zero badges, no tag scores, and no ranks while waiting for *all* of those scripts to run again and gradually make the profile look normal again.

All of the oddities will eventually resolve themselves over time. Well, everything except for a seemingly brand new user having a lot of content.

Comment: Since the unmerge does not seem to restore the account creation date, the user loses their _Yearling_ badges then? (and I guess there are a bunch of other badges that can’t be restored either, like _Announcer_ for instance)